# How to call secondary dimension in Google Analytics API

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Currently trying to get some reports using Google Analytics API using Python.

I am able to get a set of results right now for Users filtered on Campaign just fine using this.

```
dump.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            
          'dateRanges': [
                          {
                              'startDate': '7daysAgo', 
                              'endDate': 'yesterday'
                          },
                         {
                             'startDate':  '14daysAgo',
                             'endDate': '8daysAgo'
                         }
                        ],
            
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'},],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:campaign'}],
          'samplingLevel':'LARGE'
            
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```

But I would like to get a report on a secondary dimension (i.e. the view I get when I select this option on the actual Google Analytics) and I'm stuck on adding the secondary dimension. I think `ga:acquisitionSource` is the name of the field I'm trying to add.

[image: the view I want to get]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/advanced

Answer (score 2):

The [Dimensions and Metrics explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app/dimensions-metrics-explorer/) connects dimension names as displayed in the Google Analytics UI and their corresponding API name. The "Source" dimension's API name is "ga:source".

Requesting multiple dimensions is similar to the following:

```
dump.reports().batchGet(
      body={
        'reportRequests': [
        {
          'viewId': VIEW_ID,
            
          'dateRanges': [
                          {
                              'startDate': '7daysAgo', 
                              'endDate': 'yesterday'
                          },
                         {
                             'startDate':  '14daysAgo',
                             'endDate': '8daysAgo'
                         }
                        ],
            
          'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:users'},],
          'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:campaign'},{'name': 'ga:source'}],
          'samplingLevel':'LARGE'
            
        }]
      }
  ).execute()
```